# What is difference between _ID and AUDIO_ID column?

Tags: android, mediastore

I've googled it, searched on the official android docs, and found nothing satisfying. I'm developing music player app that has access to Media Storage and confused between _ID and AUDIO_ID.

What are the differences between those two? (if any)

Comment: no answer helped you to clear your confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is difference.

**_ID**

> The unique ID for a row.

**AUDIO_ID**

> The ID of the audio file

**Difference**

> _ID is column name of BASECOLUMNS database table. It is implemented in following other tables.
>
> Browser.BookmarkColumns, Browser.SearchColumns, CalendarContract.Attendees, CalendarContract.CalendarAlerts, CalendarContract.CalendarEntity, CalendarContract.Calendars, CalendarContract.Colors, CalendarContract.ColorsColumns, CalendarContract.Events, CalendarContract.EventsEntity
>
> And AUDIO_ID is part of **MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns**, which has implementation of **BASECOLUMNS** table.
>
> **MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns** : Columns for audio file that show up in multiple tables.

Reference : [_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html) , [AUDIO_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.html)

Comment: Ah, got it. So _ID is analogous to row number in SQL query result, and AUDIO_ID is more like primary key for each audio. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. _ID is primary key for each row of audio entry. But AUDIO_ID is unique id given to particular file.

Answer (score 2):

`AUDIO_ID` is the unique identifier of the audio file.

`_ID` is the identifier of the combination of playlist_id and audio_id.
In this case it's possible to have the same audio in one playlist multiple times. That's why each audiofile to playlist row has an unique identifier `_ID`.

It's basically a link table for playlists and audio, and each link has it's own `_ID`

Like this:

```
 ID    AUDIO_ID    PLAYLIST_ID
----- ----------  -------------
  1        1             1
  2        1             1           <----We can have the same combination, so we need an unique identifier.
  3        5             1
  4        8             2
```

Source: [MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.html)

Comment: so, audio files in a playlist has sequential _ID from 0 to playlist size - 1?

Comment: FYI, what I'm exactly doing is trying to get absolute reference to audio files that can be exists in multiple playlists and store them in flat file. Should I use AUDIO_ID or _ID?

Comment: It's basically a link table for playlists and audio, and each link has it's own _ID

Comment: The `audio_ID` is absolute reference to the AUDIO. Which can exists in multiple playlists.  The `ID` will refer you to an unique combination of audio within a playlist.