# Getting AUDIO_ID when querying the whole Media Store

Tags: android, mediastore

After knowing the difference between _ID and AUDIO_ID ([What is difference between _ID and AUDIO_ID column?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17648083/670623)), I'm changing my query to use AUDIO_ID instead, however I got some problem here.

Here's my code snippet that intended to query all audio files in external storage and make "Music" instances for each of them with embedded AUDIO_ID.

```
Uri uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Cursor cur = mContentResolver.query(uri, null, 
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " = 1", null, null);

int artistColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
int titleColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
int idColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID);

// All of the above columns return the right integers, 
// except idColumn which returns -1 thus making my further code below throws an exception

do{
    Music music = new Music(); // it's my music class
    music.setArtist( cur.getString(artistColumn) );
    music.setTitle( cur.getString(titleColumn) );
    music.setId( cur.getLong(idColumn) ); // error here, because idColumn = -1 (column not found)

    // ......
} while (cur.moveToNext())
```

Why can't I get the `AUDIO_ID` column when querying `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`? Is there any way to retrieve it? (any workarounds appreciated)

I need it since my app needs absolute reference to audio files as explained in an answer comment here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/17648131/670623

Thanks :)

### Edit

I found a question with solution close to what I'm searching (it can get the AUDIO_ID), but it's intended to list all audio files from **certain playlist**. While my concern is querying the **whole mediastore** for AUDIO_IDs regardless from which playlist they are.

[Given an Android music playlist name, how can one find the songs in the playlist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694909/given-an-android-music-playlist-name-how-can-one-find-the-songs-in-the-playlist)

Answer (score 4):

I did some tests with the `MediaStore.Audio.Media` and `MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members` databases.
I have created a small playlist with the same song contained several times and the database looks like this:

**Playlist Database**

```
+---------------------------+
|_ID | AUDIO_ID | songTitle |
+---------------------------+
|273 | 2913     | Alone     |
|274 | 1487     | Baby      |
|275 | 2913     | Alone     |
|276 | 2913     | Alone     |
|277 | 1487     | Baby      |
|278 | 2648     | Battery   |
+---------------------------+
```

As expected `_ID` is a locally unique identifier within this playlist. Of course there could be several other playlists with their own `_ID` identifiers. `AUDIO_ID` can't be used to identify a specific row in this database because the same song can appear multiple times in a single playlist.

`AUDIO_ID` is the globally unique identifier which is always the same for a certain song.

Now let's look at the `MediaStore.Audio.Media` database. In here, all songs known to the MediaStore system are stored.
(this is only an excerpt)

**Media Database**

```
+-------------------+
|_ID  | songTitle   |
+-------------------+
|      ....         |
|1487 | Baby        |
|      ....         |
|2648 | Battery     |
|     ....          |
|2913 | Alone       |
|     ....          |
+-------------------+
```

It seems that the `_ID` identifier in `MediaStore.Audio.Media` is used as the globally unique identifier which is called `AUDIO_ID` in the `MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members` databases.

This seems strange at first, but every song has to be contained in `MediaStore.Audio.Media` and it can only appear there **once**. And since there is only one such database, `_ID` in this database should be globally unique for each song.

Comment: Useful information which should be documented somewhere.